# How to grab the value for the previous hour when the data type is TIMESTAMP with TIMEZONE

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have some logic that will try to grab the Value (VALUE) correlated to the previous hour if the criteria are met. The HOUR column is a TIMESTAMP with TIME ZONE column.  I figured I can run the following query but got an **ORA-00932  inconsistent datatypes: expected TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE got NUMBER** error. Is there some sort of conversion function I have to add to my 'timestamp with timezone' value?

Below is my query code:

```
SELECT MAX(VALUE)
  FROM VALUE V
 WHERE CODE = 'HI'
   AND HR = '15-JAN-17 05.00.00.000000000 AM' - (1/24);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'15-JAN-17 05.00.00.000000000 AM'` is a string, not a timestamp. You can convert it to a timestamp (with no time zone) as @D-Shih suggested, but you should specify the format mask and the date language rather than relying on NLS settings:

```
AND HR = to_timestamp('15-JAN-17 05.00.00.000000000 AM', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM',
 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') - (1/24);
```

or if it's a fixed value (presumably it isn't, or you could just change that literal):

```
AND HR = timestamp '2017-01-15 05:00:00' - (1/24);
```

Subtracting a number of days from a timestamp gives you a date result, so you perhaps really want to do:

```
AND HR = timestamp '2017-01-15 05:00:00' - interval '1' hour;
```

This now stays as a timestamp, but you have no time zone information. If you know the time zone you can include it in string literal and format mask, or in the timestamp literal, e.g.:

```
AND HR = timestamp '2017-01-15 05:00:00 America/Los_Angeles' - (1/24);
```

or from your original string, if that's all you have to work with, you can use `from_tz()`:

```
AND HR = from_tz(to_timestamp('15-JAN-17 05.00.00.000000000 AM', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM',
  'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH'), 'America/Los_Angeles') - interval '1' hour;
```

Doing the interval subtraction last should mean that it handles DST properly.

Demo of the various conversions, starting from your string value:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF1';
alter session set nls_timestamp_tz_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF1 TZR TZD';

select
  to_timestamp('15-JAN-17 05.00.00.000000000 AM', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM',
    'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') as a_timestamp,
  to_timestamp('15-JAN-17 05.00.00.000000000 AM', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM',
    'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') - (1/24) as b_date,
  to_timestamp('15-JAN-17 05.00.00.000000000 AM', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM',
    'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') - interval '1' hour as c_timestamp,
  from_tz(to_timestamp('15-JAN-17 05.00.00.000000000 AM', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM',
  'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH'), 'America/Los_Angeles') - interval '1' hour as d_timestamp_tz
from dual;

A_TIMESTAMP           B_DATE              C_TIMESTAMP           D_TIMESTAMP_TZ                               
--------------------- ------------------- --------------------- ---------------------------------------------
2017-01-15 05:00:00.0 2017-01-15 04:00:00 2017-01-15 04:00:00.0 2017-01-15 04:00:00.0 AMERICA/LOS_ANGELES PST
```

Comment: Thanks! so question: if i were to reference a specific timestamp by copy and pasting it, would I still need to convert it if i were to add it to my WHERE clause?

Comment: If you copy and paste it as a string then yes. You might get away with implicit conversion but it's better not to rely on that. (If the value is coming from another table then you should join, and leave it as a timestamp not a string. No idea where it is actually coming from though, obviously.)

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole. What do I need to define the timestamp format as if the date/timestamp can be both AM and FM?  'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM/PM'? I tried that and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Just use what I showed. Having either AM or PM (not both) in the format mask will recognise either AM or PM in the string vakue.

Comment: I'm dumb. thanks. One final question:   when i do this: select HR, to_timestamp(HR, 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF. AM', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = ENGLISH') as converted, I get a "ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string" error, am i missing something?

Comment: HR is already a timestamp (with time zone); you should not be converting that to another timestamp. You are implicitly converting it to a string using NLS settings, then explicitly converting it back. At best you would just strip the time zone info. If you want to display it as a string use `to_char()`.

Comment: when i try this i still get a date format picture ends before converting entire input string error:    select HR, from_tz(to_timestamp(HR, 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF. AM'), 'UTC') as converted
   from value

Comment: See previous comment - HR  *is already a timestamp* with time zone, so you don't need or want `to_timestamp()` or `from_tz()`. I don't understand what you are trying to do. The question was about a string value you wanted to treat as a timestamp, not about something that is *already* a timestamp.

Comment: you are right. Is it okay if i open a separate question for that then? this was one of the steps I was using to try and validate this issue i was having but i didnt want to upset anyone by opening a very similar question to it that may be incorrectly seen as a duplicate... :(

Answer (score 2):

use [TO_TIMESTAMP](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm) to let `'15-JAN-17 05.00.00.000000000 AM'` to datetime then minus one hour.

```
SELECT MAX(VALUE)
  FROM VALUE V
 WHERE CODE = 'HI'
   AND HR =  TO_TIMESTAMP('15-JAN-17 05.00.00.000000000 AM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM') - (1/24);
```

Comment: what if i want to do HR  = from_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP((HR) - (1/24), 'UTC') ?  I get an error when i try this.

Comment: Sind HR is a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type the query actually does `SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(HR) =  SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP('15-JAN-17 05.00.00.000000000 AM'), SESSIONTIMEZONE) - (1/24))` - is that what you need?

Comment: Using `TO_TIMESTAMP()` without explicit format definition is always a bad idea.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Yes, your suggestion is right thank for your remind

Comment: So what I am trying to do is grab a converted value (the hour before the value present in HR). I've tried    /*select hr, hr - (1/24) as CONVERTED from value */

Comment: Also @Wernfried Domscheit , how do you get your code to show up like that in the comments? i've tried (as you see above) but i obviously failed.

Comment: @JohnWick, enclose it by backticks i.e. `` - also the "help" link may help :-)